# Java parsing of dotted identifiers

Tags: java, identifier

What are the rules Java uses to resolve dotted identifiers?

For example:

```
import Foo.Bar;

class Foo
{
    public static class Bar
    {
    };
};
```

Now, `Foo.Bar` can refer to either the imported class `Bar` or the one defined in the source code. How is this kind of ambiguity resolved?

I have tried this one case so I know what happens in practice, but I'm looking for more than that; I want to know the underlying rules. For example, if `Foo.Bar` exists in the source file, can I still refer to the imported class `Foo.Bar.Baz`? What if `Foo.Bar` is a package and also a class? If the compiler can't find `Foo.Bar` in the closest `Foo`, does it just give up, or does it keep looking for other `Foo`s until it either runs out or finds one that matches?

(Incidentally, I have found the relevant bit in the language specification. It doesn't help much...)

Comment: If all code follows the recommended Java naming conventions, then this never arises: package names are always fully lower-case, and class names always start with an uppercase letter. If your code doesn't follow that convention, well, what you see in the language specification is what you get.

Comment: True, but not what I was asking...

Comment: Right, and that's why my comment is a comment, not an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

To resolve a weird clash like this, the java compiler follows the same rules it uses to resolve things like local variable names clashing with instance field names - it uses the "nearest" declaration. In this case, the local class Foo will win over the imported one.

A clash can also happen when two classes of the same name is being imported. The most common example is `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. If you have imported them both into your class, you must refer to them using their fully qualified name.

Comment: -1 for ignoring the question - "I have tried this one case so I know what happens in practice, but I'm looking for more than that; I want to know the underlying rules."

Comment: I notice that not only does trying to import both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` fails, but importing `java.util.*` and `java.sql.*` now errors if I refer to an unqualified `Date` --- which is a level of intelligence that frankly I wasn't expecting. What about the case when `Foo` exists locally, hiding the imported `Foo`, but does not provide `Foo.Bar` but the imported one does? Will the local one prevent access to `Foo.Bar` (which would seem sensible)? And is there any way to access the global namespace explicitly, like a leading `::` in C++?